# Is it possible to disable adding of empty row in spreadsheet using a Userform in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Hello so I have a code here that allows me to add/insert a new row in the spreadsheet using a userform, however it also allows me to add BLANK/EMPTY rows. Does anyone know how to disable that? I have no knowledge in coding so I base on tutorials but I couldn't seem to find one.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmbAdd_Click()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TRY TRY")

    nextrow = sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 1) = Me.cmbSchema
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 2) = Me.cmbEnvironment
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 3) = Me.cmbHost
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 4) = Me.cmbIP
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 5) = Me.cmbAccessible
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 6) = Me.cmbLast
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 7) = Me.cmbConfirmation
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 8) = Me.cmbProjects

    MsgBox "Data Added!"

End Sub
```

Can I have a MsgBox again saying "You cannot add empty rows." ?

Comment: For this to be the case, all of your textboxes would need to be empty. So just check `If Me.cmbSchema = ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, change sheet name in case of your sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TRY_TRY")

    nextrow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If Me.cmbSchema = "" Or _
        Me.cmbEnvironment = "" Or _
        Me.cmbHost = "" Or _
        Me.cmbIP = "" Or _
        Me.cmbAccessible = "" Or _
        Me.cmbLast = "" Or _
        Me.cmbConfirmation = "" Or _
        Me.cmbProjects = "" Then

        MsgBox "Empty value is not allowed", vbCritical, "Data Missing"

    Else

        sht.Cells(nextrow, 1) = Me.cmbSchema
        sht.Cells(nextrow, 2) = Me.cmbEnvironment
        sht.Cells(nextrow, 3) = Me.cmbHost
        sht.Cells(nextrow, 4) = Me.cmbIP
        sht.Cells(nextrow, 5) = Me.cmbAccessible
        sht.Cells(nextrow, 6) = Me.cmbLast
        sht.Cells(nextrow, 7) = Me.cmbConfirmation
        sht.Cells(nextrow, 8) = Me.cmbProjects

        MsgBox "Data Added!"

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! Your process works and is easier to code than multiple me.cmbSchema = "".

Comment: Glad to know it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub cmbAdd_Click()

If IsEmpty(Me.cmbSchema) Then
    MsgBox "cmbSchema is blank!"
    Exit Sub
End If


'....Rest of code goes here


End Sub
```

Comment: I was still able to add empty row :(

Comment: I only coded for one blank text box as an example. You will need to code for each one

Comment: Yup I did it. However it still didn't work. I tried this code if (Me.cmbSchema = "") then and it worked. I removed IsEmpty. Thanks for your idea!